# combine multiple rows result into one row

Tags: sql, oracle, listagg

I want to combine multiple results in one row using XMLAGG function 
here is what i am using

```
RTRIM(XMLAGG(XMLELEMENT(E,B.TEAM_NAME,',').EXTRACT('//text()') ORDER BY 
B.TEAM_NAME ).GetClobVal(),',') MY_TEAM_NAMES, 
RTRIM(XMLAGG(XMLELEMENT(E,A.TEAM_NAME,',').EXTRACT('//text()') ORDER BY 
A.TEAM_NAME).GetClobVal(),',') YOUR_TEAM_NAMES
```

i want to get unique results and combine them in one row for both columns.
currently i am getting result as below:-

```
MY_TEAM_NAMES                 
Klaus Directs,Klaus Directs,Klaus Directs,Klaus team,Klaus team,Night Riders,Night Riders

YOUR_TEAM_NAMES
Beckham Team,Louise Golf Team,Louise Golf Team,Louise Golf Team,Louise Peers,Louise Peers,Louise Peers
```

But i want to remove duplicate values from both MY_TEAM_NAMES and YOUR_TEAM_NAMES.

There is one solution to use distinct keyword in from clause which is not possible to use in this case. and these results are originally coming as relation in below format:

```
MY_TEAM_NAMES   YOUR_TEAM_NAMES 
Klaus Directs   Louise Peers
Night Riders    Louise Peers
Klaus Directs   Beckham Team
Klaus Directs   Louise Golf Team
Klaus team      Louise Peers
Klaus team      Louise Golf Team
Night Riders    Louise Golf Team
```

Comment: Sample data would be helpful.  Your query refers to two tables but your description suggests there is only one.

Comment: Couldn't you apply the `XMLAGG` on already distinctly selected values?

Answer (score 0):

You can try use `distinct` before main query... for example:

```
with tmpT as 
(
select 'Klaus Directs' as MY_TEAM_NAMES, 'Louise Peers' as YOUR_TEAM_NAMES from dual
union all select 'Night Riders', 'Louise Peers' from dual
union all select 'Klaus Directs', 'Beckham Team' from dual
union all select 'Klaus Directs', 'Louise Golf Team' from dual
union all select 'Klaus team', 'Louise Peers' from dual
union all select 'Klaus team', 'Louise Golf Team' from dual
union all select 'Night Riders', 'Louise Golf Team' from dual
)
select listagg(decode(typeR,1,TEAM_NAMES,null),', ') within group (order by TEAM_NAMES) as MY_TEAM_NAMES 
     , listagg(decode(typeR,2,TEAM_NAMES,null),', ') within group (order by TEAM_NAMES) as YOUR_TEAM_NAMES
  from (select distinct MY_TEAM_NAMES as TEAM_NAMES, 1 as typeR from tmpT
        union select distinct YOUR_TEAM_NAMES, 2 from tmpT
       )
```

Comment: i cannot use distinct before main query because it will give me distinct combination of both teams, but my final result should be 
MY_TEAM_NAMES
Night Riders,Klaus directs, Klaus Team
YOUR_TEAM_NAMES
Louise Peers, Becham Team, Louise Golf Team
that means final result should have two column with names MY_TEAM_NAMES and YOUR_TEAM_NAMES and there should be only one result without repition of teams in both MY_TEMA_NAMES and YOUR_TEAM_NAMES as i decribed above.